# Prove that an algorithm cannot reach a given goal

Tags: invariance

We are given an algorithm that, in each step takes a set $\left\{a, b, c\right\}$ It takes any two variables $a, b$ at random and changes them to $0.6 + 0.8b$ and $0.8a - 0.6b$. The initial value of the algorithm is $\left\{3, 4, 12\right\}$. Prove that the algorithm cannot reach $\left\{x, y, z\right\}$ where $|x - 4|, |y - 6|, |z - 12| < \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$.

I realized straight away that this could be solved using invariance. The invariant was easy to find: It was the function $f_i(a, b, c) = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$. This function gives the same value for any step $i$ of the algorithm. $f(3, 4, 12) = 169$.

It remained to prove that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \neq 169$. Now, I started off  by adding the inequalities given in the statement:

$(x - 4)^2 + (y - 6)^2 + (z-12)^2 < 3\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right)^2 = 1$

$\implies x^2 + 16 - 8x + y^2 + 36 - 12y + z^2 + 144 - 24z < 1$

$\implies x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 8x + 12y + 24z - 195$

This is where I was stuck. How do I prove that $8x + 12y + 24z - 195 < 169$?

Comment: The last equation is not necessarily true because we can take $x=4$, $y=6$ and $z=12$ and we get $197<169$

Comment: Yes, we have to essentially prove that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \neq 169$. But, I assumed that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 169$ and set out to prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start.  Now what are the minimum values that $x,y,z$ can take?  Add their squares and you are home.

Comment: What do you mean by 'minimum values'?

Comment: You must have $x \ge 4-\frac 1{\sqrt 3}$ and similar relations for $y,z$.  If you square those and add them up, that is the minimum value $x^2+y^2+z^2$ can take, and is greater than $169$

Comment: Yes,  that's right. I was thrown off by the absolute value. Thanks.

Comment: You have shown that all reachable values are on a sphere of radius 13.  The problem asks if you can reach a value within a cube centered at $(4,6,12)$ of side $\frac 2{\sqrt 3}$  Essentially you are proving that there is no intersection between these.  If there were an intersection, you wouldn't know if you could reach such a point or not (at least not this way).

Answer (score 1):

You are transforming via multiplication by the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
.6 &  .8 & 0\\
.8 & -.6 & 0\\
 0 &   0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}.
$$
So the third element always stays fixed at it's initial value. The motion of the first two is given by the matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
.6 &  .8\\
.8 & -.6
\end{bmatrix},
\text{ and } A^2 = I.
$$
Therefore, the first two elements will oscillate between $(3,4)$ and $(5,0)$ while the third one stays the same at 12. Your conclusions follows immediately.

Comment: This is not correct, as the two elements to change are randomly selected.  $c$ can be changed as the two numbers to change are randomly selected.

Comment: @RossMillikan: The OP has changed the question.

Comment: I just noticed the edit.  Your answer handles the original version.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I forgot to mention that the algorithm chose variables randomly.

Answer (score 1):

You should study the function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ in the domain $[4-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}]\times [6-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}]\times [12-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}]$. It is "obvious" (but you can prove it using, for instance, lagrange multipliers) that the minimum of the function is $f(4-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},6-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},12-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})=197-\frac{44}{\sqrt{3}}\sim 171.59$, so that $169$ is not in the image.